# Proxy Error 502 Openshift

Tags: php, curl, openshift

I'am using Openshift Demo in my local machine and Drupal project, when i submit in a form.php i need to create an app with the REST API with the curl lib, and i get the :

```
Proxy Error 502
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

I don't have any suspect things in all my logs files, also i change all params (TimeOut, size ..) in the haproxy config, httpd.conf, broker.conf and i still have the error so any ideas why this error ?

This my curl code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, null);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name=test&cartridge[url]=my_Cartridge_URL');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $server_output_app_create = curl_exec ($ch);
    drupal_set_message(''. print_r($server_output_app_create, TRUE) .'');
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Thanks

Comment: Followup?  What did you find?  What fixed your issue?  thanks.

Comment: was this solved? if not, some more info about your environment would be nice